# How do you wildcard or string pattern match with XSLTv1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

My XML data contains the following:

```
    <Cookies>
    </Cookie>
    <Cookie name="PD_STATEFUL_2707f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953888d">
    <Value>%2Fportal</Value>
    <Path>/</Path><Domain></Domain><Expires></Expires><Secure>0</Secure> 
    <HTTPOnly>0</HTTPOnly>
    </Cookie>
    <Cookie name="PD_STATEFUL_2808f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d">
    <Value>%2Fwasapp</Value>
    <Path>/</Path><Domain></Domain><Expires></Expires><Secure>0</Secure> 
    <HTTPOnly>0</HTTPOnly>
    </Cookie>
    </Cookies>
```

Using XLSTv1.0, how do I modify the following code to set attributes for all cookies starting with PD_STATEFUL_* rather than coding each specific cookie name?

```
    <xsl:template match="//HTTPResponse/Cookies">
        <xsl:if test="Cookie/@name='PD_STATEFUL_2707f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d'">
            <Cookie action="update" name="PD_STATEFUL_2707f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d">
                <Secure>1</Secure>
                <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
            </Cookie>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="Cookie/@name='PD_STATEFUL_2808f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d'">
            <Cookie action="update" name="PD_STATEFUL_2808f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d">
                <Secure>1</Secure>
                <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
            </Cookie>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Since I was not sure about your expected output I have provided 2 stylesheets:

1) Keep the same structure of the `Cookie` node and just change the values of elements `Secure` and `HTTPOnly` to `1` and add the `action="update"` attribute

2) Remove all other sub nodes of the `Cookie` node on top of adding the `action="update"` attribute and changing the value of `Secure` and `HTTPOnly` to `1`

**INPUT:**

```
::::::::::::::
cookies.xml
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cookies>
  <Cookie name="PD_STATEFUL_2707f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953888d">
    <Value>%2Fportal</Value>
    <Path>/</Path>
    <Domain/>
    <Expires/>
    <Secure>0</Secure>
    <HTTPOnly>0</HTTPOnly>
  </Cookie>
  <Cookie name="PD_STATEFUL_2808f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d">
    <Value>%2Fwasapp</Value>
    <Path>/</Path>
    <Domain/>
    <Expires/>
    <Secure>0</Secure>
    <HTTPOnly>0</HTTPOnly>
  </Cookie>
</Cookies>
```

**CASE 1**

STYLESHEET:

```
::::::::::::::
cookies.xsl
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]">
        <Cookie action="update" name="{./@name}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Cookie>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]/Secure/text()">1</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]/HTTPOnly/text()">1</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EXPLANATIONS:

Copy every node/attribute then when reaching nodes that respect the condition `Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]` you add the attribute `action="update"` use the same attribute `name="{./@name}"` and then copy everything under this element when reaching `Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]/Secure/text()` and `Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]/HTTPOnly/text()` the template will be triggered and the value will be set to 1. Other Cookie that do not respect  `starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')` will not be affected by this change.

OUTPUT:

```
$xsltproc cookies.xsl cookies.xml | xmllint --format -                                                                         
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Cookies>
  <Cookie action="update" name="PD_STATEFUL_2707f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953888d">
    <Value>%2Fportal</Value>
    <Path>/</Path>
    <Domain/>
    <Expires/>
    <Secure>1</Secure>
    <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
  </Cookie>
  <Cookie action="update" name="PD_STATEFUL_2808f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d">
    <Value>%2Fwasapp</Value>
    <Path>/</Path>
    <Domain/>
    <Expires/>
    <Secure>1</Secure>
    <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
  </Cookie>
</Cookies>
```

**CASE2:**

STYLESHEET:

```
::::::::::::::
cookies2.xsl
::::::::::::::
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')]">
        <Cookie action="update" name="{./@name}">
                <Secure>1</Secure>
                <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
        </Cookie>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EXPLANATION:

Here when reaching nodes that respect `Cookie[starts-with(@name,'PD_STATEFUL_')`
we overwrite the node content to

```
        <Cookie action="update" name="{./@name}">
                <Secure>1</Secure>
                <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
        </Cookie>
```

Therefore other subnodes will be lost.

OUTPUT:

```
$ xsltproc cookies2.xsl cookies.xml | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Cookies>
  <Cookie action="update" name="PD_STATEFUL_2707f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953888d">
    <Secure>1</Secure>
    <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
  </Cookie>
  <Cookie action="update" name="PD_STATEFUL_2808f5b6-48e3-11e8-bb87-000c2953180d">
    <Secure>1</Secure>
    <HTTPOnly>1</HTTPOnly>
  </Cookie>
</Cookies>
```